# R readr: How do I define multiple comment characters in read_csv()?

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read a csv file with R `readr::read_csv()`.

The csv file has comment lines that I would like to ignore, some of which start with "#" and others start with "Subject".

I can get R to ignore one of them, e.g. with

`read_csv("data.csv", comment = "#")` or `read_csv("data.csv", comment = "Subject")`

But how do I define both as comments? This was my idea, but it produced an error message:

`read_csv("data.csv", comment = c("#", "Subject"))`

Can anyone help me out? This is my first question here, I hope the format is alright. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have legitimate lines that could start with the same character as the comments, I would just read it in with one comment character, e.g. `#` and then delete the lines that start with the other. Something like:

```r
library(readr)
df  <- read_csv("./comments.csv", comment = "#")

starts_with_subject  <- sapply(df[1], function(x) substr(x,1,7)=="Subject")
df  <- df[!starts_with_subject,]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I was hoping for a solution within readr that (being a beginner) I just hadn't found yet. If I need to implement an extra step after `read_csv()`, could I also use `df <- df %>% filter(Var1 != "Subject")`? Or would this be considered bad/worse coding for some reason?

Comment: In general it is better to use variable names than column-indexing, as it's less brittle if the data changes at some future point. Having said that, in this particular example, you always want the first column, so using indexing might be better. I don't think it really matters. As for `==` vs `substr()`, your way is better if you are certain that the comment lines only contain the word `Subject`. However if they may contain additional characters that could get read into the first column (including spaces), then a solution looking at what the row starts with is better.

Comment: Sam, I think I now also found a one-step solution for my problem by using `readr::read_csv_chunked()` instead of `readr::read_csv()`; could you tell me if this is ok too or if it is problematic for some reason?  
`readr::read_csv_chunked("data.csv", comment = "#", callback = DataFrameCallback$new(function(x, pos) subset(x, Var1 != "Subject")))`

Comment: Interesting but basically doing the same thing, just in chunks. Might be worth it if you have a very large csv with lots of lines you don't want to read in, although the speed would depend on how frequently you have to do the `subset` operation (i.e. how frequent are the comment lines and are they placed contiguously), as generally doing it lots of times will become expensive compared with doing it once.